# with LINQ, how to transfer a List<List<string>> to List<string>?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I got an object of

```
List<List<string>>
```

I need to bring this into a

```
List<string>
```

I have no idea how to do this with LINQ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
List<string> results = original.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: so this is what SelectMany does... thanks, waiting the usual 10 minutes and marking it green

Comment: @Fredou, In query expression terms, you would write `(from list in lists from item in list select item).ToList()`